# Design an item filter module considering mutual exclusive conditions

Tags: database, oracle, web

As we all know, many shopping or searching websites allows the web display multiple filter conditions for users to choose, and choose again...
In my project, i also have multiple filter conditions categorized into different classes, but some conditions(classes) are mutually exclusive, i.e. once a condition is chosen, its exclusive conditions shouldn't be displayed for further filter.
My problem is should i hard code all these exclusive rules like 'if condition 1 then only show other allowed conditions' ?
or can i design a few tables contain these conditions and their constraints so that i can display allowed conditions just by 'Select xxx from xx where **'
or what is the best production practice to solve my problem?